# Is it possible to set maxConcurrentPublishedTracks through the twilio rest api?

Tags: audio, twilio, twilio-api

Now.. we are facing audio problems when participants are more than 5 in the video room.

at this moment, I want to test about maxConcurrentPublishedTracks in the room attributes.
because when I create video room as group type, the value is set as 170.

Is it possible to set maxConcurrentPublishedTracks through twili rest api?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set `maxConcurrentPublishedTracks` through the REST API.

I recommend you read through the documentation on [developing high quality video applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/developing-high-quality-video-applications) and understanding the various APIs that are available to you to control the quality, like the [Network Bandwidth API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/using-bandwidth-profile-api) and the [Track Priority API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/using-track-priority-api). That will give you a good toolbox to improve your application.